# Simple implementation of Apriori algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithms

I am preparing a lecture on data mining algorithms in R and I want to demonstrate the famous [Apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) in it.

**My question**
Could anybody point me to a simple implementation of this algorithm in R?

(I am not looking for a package, e.g. arules, but for comprehensible source code of an implementation from scratch. It also does not help to look at the source code of arules: It just calls a C implementation of the algorithm!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the following reference out?
Link: http://www.borgelt.net/docs/apriori.pdf

The above link has the explanation along with the code.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. You link does not work by the way.

Comment: This is the author of the C library that is being used by the arules package btw.

Comment: My bad, not sure how [1] got appended at the end. The idea with sharing this implementation( as implemented in the arules pkg) was the explanation stated along the side. Using that one can write the same in R. What do you think ? I read more into your question. Let me see if i can help you out more.

Comment: Would you be able to write it in R? It seems pretty involved...

Comment: I don't think Apriori can be efficiently/elegantly implemented in R *at all*. The language is just not designed for such operations. Compare the fastest R implementation you can find to a C implementation such that of Borgelt. I bet there is a factor of 100x or more in difference; and probably growing with data set size. And this will just *kill* you on any realistic data set when attempting to do this in plain R.

Comment: I think @vonjd just needs a simple implementation to demonstrate the algorithm, just a prototype.

Comment: Note that the description of "prune" in this pdf is incomplete. It never prunes anything, and never uses s_min (it's fairly obvious what is missing, though). In candidates, it does not explicitly exploit that the frequent itemset are always sorted, which improves runtime substantially (one may argue this to be hidden in the "with" condition). But **do use Christian Borgelt's implementations** (via the `arules` package)!

Comment: (I'm *not* sure if the `arules` package has his latest version, though!)

Answer (score 2):

I found an implementation here: [Learning Data Mining with R by Bater Makhabel](https://books.google.de/books?id=ifpzBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA50&ots=rkVf2uZvYo&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q&f=false)

The source code can be downloaded here: https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/learning-data-mining-r

Comment: It's walled, requires registration. How does it benchmark, compared to e.g. arules, on some classic benchmark sets?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: I haven't benchmarked it but I expect it to be considerably slower because arules calls, as I wrote in my question, a compiled C implementation.

Comment: Yes, but it would be good to be able to put a number on that. Two orders of magnitude, or four? Because in my experience, plain R code is *incredibly* slow (so it does not make sense to even start implementing such algorithms in R in my opinion).

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: It can make sense for pedagogical reasons, to understand the underlying concepts and algorithms.

Comment: I disagree. It only teaches them to use the wrong tools the wrong way. You are better off using pseudocode that doesn't bother with irrelevant syntax hacks necessary to make it work in R. Your students will be fighting with R code they'll never use, and miss the subtle details of Apriori. I just had a look at this Apriori implementation, and it already lacks some of these simple yet efficient optimizations that simply exploit the sortedness and drastically reduce the apriori-gen cost. Focus on the key ideas of generating as few candidates, and clever pruning instead.

Comment: Which is why I'd really like to see a benchmark comparison... because it is not just R, there are also algorithmic aspects that tend to get lost when people try to do a "simple implementation". It's no longer Apriori then, if all the good parts are left away for simplicity.